# How to extend for bespoke classes in UI5 (not custom controls)

Tags: sapui5

Using the AMD and module paradigm used by UI5, I want to use separate JS classes in distinct JS files to separate my ajax code from the related controllers.

A foundation class will be concerned with common activity such as generic error handling whilst specific classes extending from this will deal with subject-specific ajax communication only. This will NOT be a custom control so no requirement for render capability, metadata, etc.

I wish to benefit from the sap.ui.define functionality and also want my new class to be good UI5 citizen. For example I want to fire my init when the class is instantiated.

Which sapui5 class or classes should I extend from? I am currently using sap/ui/base/Object but would like to know if there is a better choice based on better performance or better fit to purpose.

I am aware of the [documentation on custom controls](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw75/helpdata/en/d1/2d2ee6a5454d799358d425f9e7c4db/content.htm) but this seems to focus only on details of classes that render to screen.

This is the skeleton of my current approach:

```
sap.ui.define(['sap/ui/base/Object'],

    function(BaseObject) {
        "use strict";

        var AjaxBase = BaseObject.extend("myAjaxBase", {

            constructor: function(oControl) {
                BaseObject.apply(this);
                console.log("AjaxBase.constructor() fires")
            }
        })

        AjaxBase.prototype.init = function() {
            console.log("AjaxBase.init() fires")
        }
        return AjaxBase;

}, true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sap.ui.define` even for objects which do not extend `sap.ui.base.Object`. So if you do not really need functionality provided by UI5 objects you are not forced to extend them. However, in your case it looks like you want to use event support and in this case it would be useful to at least extend `sap.ui.base.EventProvider`.

As you want to separate backend calls from your controllers it looks like you are using a JSONModel and have more complex use cases than just reads. In this case you could also extend the JSONModel with support for create, update and delete operations.